# Multiplication of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

So, I'm reading through this old math book (title doesn't matter).

I'm in the section that talks about multiplying polynomials. I've read it and completely understand it. I did all the exercises and pretty much got all of them correct.

For extra practice though, I decided to write a few of my own problems and solve them.

Instantly, the technique that the book teaches just uberly fails. Here are some examples of questions I made up:

$$(3x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2 + 4x^2y)(3x - 4y^3 + 7x^2)$$

$$(3xy + 4y^2 - 7x)(5x + 2y)$$

I just can't see why these aren't solvable and

$$(2a - 3b)(3a^2 - 2ab + 4b^2)$$

$$(2x^2 - 3xy + y^2)(3x^2 - xy + 2y^2)$$

...the above ones are. What's the difference?

---

For the record, the book teaches that the problem should be solved by distributing the polynomials and adding the like-terms. The problem I'm having with my expressions is that I'm not getting like-terms.

Comment: What do you mean solvable?

Comment: Tip: [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is way faster and looks better than html

Comment: By "solvable", I mean "simplifiable". Not trying to be rude, but please don't be pedantic

Comment: The distributive law should work just fine. Could you explain the results you are getting so someone can try to understand where the problem is arising?

Comment: It's kind of hard to do because I'll lose the whitespace formatting...

Comment: `The problem I'm having with my expressions is that I'm not getting like-terms` That's correct, some products won't have `like-terms`. For example $(x+1)(y+1)=x+y+x y +1$ is not `simplifiable` further. As long as you calculate the correct product, this in itself is not a problem.

Comment: +dxiv why isn't it is my question. (x+1) is the same as (x+1x^0) and (y+1 is the same as (y+1y^0) you should able to distribute the polynomials

Answer (score 2):

For example, in your first case you should get
$$(3x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2 + 4x^2y)(3x - 4y^3+7x^2) =
-16\,{x}^{2}{y}^{4}+28\,{x}^{4}y-12\,{x}^{2}{y}^{3}-16\,x{y}^{4}-20\,{
y}^{5}+21\,{x}^{4}+40\,{x}^{3}y+35\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+9\,{x}^{3}+12\,{x}^
{2}y+15\,x{y}^{2}
 $$
There are $11$ terms on the right side, while the two factors had $4$ and $3$.  So there were just two "like terms" that combined into one.  Well, that's life: sometimes there may be more, sometimes less.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was a bit confused because the book I have only gave me problems where all of the terms could be combined in right-shifting added columns like a giant multiplication problem. I was confused because I assumed this was the standard notation, and apparently it's just some ignorant way of visualizing a handful of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like terms are those which have same variables no matter coefficients are similar or different.

e.g. $4 x^{2}$ and $ 6 x^{2},$

$2x^3yz$  and $ -6x^3yz$ are like terms.

$(3xy+4y^2−7x)(5x+2y)$

$=3xy(5x+2y)+4y^2(5x+2y)$

$= 15x^2y +6xy^2 + 20xy^2 + 8y^3 - 35x^2 -14xy$

here, $6xy^2$ and $20xy^2$ are like terms

$= 15x^2y + 26xy^2 + 8y^3 - 35x^2 -14xy $

Apply this method using different expression.